# Pygame Key Event On Press, Different Event On Hold

Tags: python-3.x, animation, pygame

What I am looking for is smooth sprite animations, with transition animations in between them. instead of the main character blinking left or right then doing movement animations, it does another animation of turning around before continuing.

So i want a pygame KEYDOWN event to do a task, then i want the animation to elapse (I think it is 270~ milliseconds, or 16 frames at 60 fps), then i want a different animation to play repeatedly for as long as the button is held down, without repeating the transition over and over, which is what i've currently got.
relevant loop is here:

```
while Playing:
dt = Clock.tick()/1000
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()


for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

if event.type == KEYDOWN:


    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        walkerspritesheet = WalkerStandToSlow_Right_List
        walkerxlocation += walkermovespeed
        if Walker_Counter == 16:
            walkerspritesheet = WalkerSlow_Right_List

    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        walkerspritesheet = WalkerStandToSlow_Left_List
        walkerxlocation -= walkermovespeed
        if Walker_Counter == 16:
            walkerspritesheet = WalkerSlow_Left_List
```

The XXXXX_List variables are lists of sprite sheet slices. Farther down the main while loop, it plays an animation of the Walker, using the images contained in walkerspritesheet. Walker_Counter is which frame out of 60 the animation is at.

Let me know if i'm missing any necessary information, thanks.

Comment: Your keydown event handler sets your sprite state (e.g. walking left). If you clear that state in a keyup event handler, then you can update the sprite in your main loop to repeat the animation as long as the key is held.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. The keyup section handles switching from walking, to transition, to idle animations. That works, because keyup is only recieved for a frame, keydown is continuous. I am looking for more like,

Comment: Whoops, enter posts immediately. I am looking for more like, on keydown: walkerspritesheet = WalkerStandToSLow_Right_List.' and as soon as it reaches the condition, like count to 16 frames for the length of the transition, then walkerspritesheet = WalkerSlow_Right_List. the problem I'm having is how to have this happen out of the loop so it doesn't play the transition every time instead of the walking animation. is there a function that will receive a keydown only on the first instant it is pressed for the idle-to-walking transition? then holding the key down sets to the walking animation.

Comment: Events should change game/sprite state. The state of the game should be handled outside of the event handler. [This book](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html#the-game-loop) has some more information on the game loop concept.

Comment: Read through most of it, still don't really understand, this is hurting my brain. all I need is something that count time elapsed from a certain time, without pausing the rest of the program, so time.wait wont help. I've read about pygame.time.get_ticks, but every article I see about it confuses me further... I think I have to set a variable by get_ticks for the baseline, then set another variable to get_ticks later, and read the difference between them. But the start time would need to be reset when player presses a key, which means it is read every frame again, and I'm back to square one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to create a minimal example. When you press the right or left arrow keys the sprite will move. Initially the sprite will change to a light colour, then a dark colour. When the key is released, it will return to its original colour.

[image: Example animation]

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width = 320
height = 240
FPS = 30

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, starting_position=(0,0)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        width, height = 10, 20
        self.color= pygame.Color("brown")
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #initialise position
        self.rect.center = starting_position
        self.velx = 0
        self.counter = 0

    def animate(self):
        if self.velx == 0:
            self.image.fill(self.color)  # reset to original image
        else:
            self.counter += 1  # increment counter
        if self.velx > 0:  # moving right
            if self.counter < 20:
                self.image.fill(pygame.Color("lightgreen"))
            else:
                self.image.fill(pygame.Color("darkgreen"))
        elif self.velx < 0:  # moving left
            if self.counter < 20:
                self.image.fill(pygame.Color("lightblue"))
            else:
                self.image.fill(pygame.Color("darkblue"))

    def stop(self):
        self.velx = 0
        self.counter = 0

    def move_left(self):
        self.velx -= 1

    def move_right(self):
        self.velx += 1        

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.rect.x += self.velx
        # check bounds
        if not 0 < self.rect.x < (width - 20):
            self.rect.x -= self.velx  # out of bounds, undo movement

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.center)

player = Player((50, 100))
done = False
# main loop
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():            
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move_left()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move_right()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                player.stop()

    # update sprite(s)
    player.update()
    #redraw screen
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("black")) # use black background
    # draw sprite
    player.draw(screen)
    # update screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Let me know if you have any questions.